# Images get resized to 0 x 0 in heroku app

Tags: html, css, heroku

I have a simple webpage hosted on Heroku. There are 4 images which get resized to 0x0 automatically while it shows up perfectly fine on localhost. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

What it looks like on localhost
[image: original]

What it looks like on heroku
[image: heroku]

The grey background is because the next section has that background which means the image's size is 0x0.

To verify, I inspected the source code through developer tools.
[image: chrome dev tools]

```
<div class="section2">
    <div class="heading">POWERED BY</div>
    <div class="logos">
        <a href="https://www.jamboreeindia.com/">
            <div class="sponsor-logo">
                <img src="jamboree3.png" class="overlay-logo">
                <img src="jamboree.png" class="original-logo">
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.megalogix.org/">
            <div class="sponsor-logo">
                <img src="mcs2.png" class="overlay-logo">
                <img src="mcs.png" class="original-logo">
            </div>
        </a>            
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section2{
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0; 
}

.heading{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #9FACCC;
}

.heading2{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.logos{
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sponsor-logo img{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 50px;
}

.original-logo {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.overlay-logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.overlay-logo:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.overlay-logo:hover + .original-logo {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: umm, you image src is an absolute path not relative, so I think you are not getting the images, try changing <img src="mcs2.png" class="overlay-logo"> to <img src="/mcs2.png" class="overlay-logo">, where does your image sit? just in the root folder?

Comment: @Mindless, it doesn't make a change. Also, images are loading fine as per the Sources tab in the dev tools.

Comment: @Mindless yes they are in the root directory.

Comment: do you have the url so i can have a look?

Comment: http://xino19.herokuapp.com/index.html

Comment: image is showing - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHnE9.png

Comment: Umm I didn't understand. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why, disable your Adblocker on that site, it's blocking the images and injecting a style to the "sponsor-logo" class

```
{
    display: none!important;
}
```